# Java File input problems

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

I am having a problem getting my program to read from a file. I am using Netbeans 7.4 and I have included the text file in the source folder where the .java files are. The program should open a text file and return the number of lines. I believe the problem has to do with the way I am handling the file because for this program I am using a class for doing the wordcounting, another class for doing the file handling, and another class to test my classes.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class WordCountTest {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            // Gets the file name from the user and creates a new FileHandle
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Input File: ");
            String inputFileName = console.next();
            FileHandle inputFileHandle = new FileHandle(inputFileName);

            try{
                // get the File object from the FileHandle
                File inputFile = inputFileHandle.getFile();
                // Create a new WordCount object with the input file
                WordCount fileCount = new WordCount(inputFile);
                // Print out the line numbers
                System.out.println(fileCount.getLineNumber());
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

FileHandle Class:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class FileHandle {
        // Instance Variables
        private File inputFile;
        private String inputFileName;

        /**
         * Constructor for the FileHandle Class.
         * @param file the String representation of the file name
         */
        public FileHandle(String file)
        {
            this.inputFileName = file;
        }

        /**
         * Method for creating a file object based on the String name passed
         * @return File object
         * @throws FileNotFoundException 
         */
        public File getFile() throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            File inputFile = new File(this.inputFileName);
            return inputFile;
        }
    }
```

Word Count Class:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class WordCount {
        // Instance variabkes
        private File inputFile;
        private int lineNumber=0;

        /**
         * Constructor for the WordCount class
         * @param inputFile File object
         */
        public WordCount(File inputFile)
        {
            this.inputFile = inputFile;
        }

        /**
         * Method that counts the line numbers for a file
         * @return the number of line numbers
         * @throws FileNotFoundException 
         */
        public int getLineNumber() throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            // New Scanner to read from the file
            Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

            // Increment the lineNumber counter if theres a next line
            while(in.hasNextLine())
            {
                lineNumber++;
            }

            return lineNumber;
        }
    }
```

This is what my output looks like:

```
    run:
    Input File: mary.txt
    Error
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure, I have it at ...NetBeansProjects\WordCount\src\source Which is where the java files are in the package

Comment: Instead of printing out `Error`, at least output the exception's stack trace. Also, if you use Java 7, do yourself a favour and use the new file API.

Comment: Java.io.FileNotFoundException: mary.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
 at source.WordCount.getLineNumber(WordCount.java:39)
 at source.WordCountTest.main(WordCountTest.java:35)

Comment: So yup looks like it can't find the file. I Will look into the Java 7 new file API but for now I was trying to do it the way it is in the textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach works if the file is in the working directory of the project (or where you run your ant target from). This is because you are giving the relative file path. Giving the absolute file path should work. If you are trying to read the file from the classpath u should  use ClassLoader's getInputStream method.

Comment: So I tried giving the program the full file path but it just hangs there until I stop it, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

run:
Input File: C:\\Users\\aaron\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WordCount\\src\\source\\mary.txt
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 15 seconds)

Comment: Thanks! I used System.out.println(inputFile.getCanonicalPath()); to get the path where the program was looking and was able to fix it that way

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing out "Error" in the catch block. Why don't you temporarily use e.printStackTrace(). It should point toward the problem causing function.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it is because the file is not found:

Java.io.FileNotFoundException: mary.txt (The system cannot find the file specified) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146) at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656) at source.WordCount.getLineNumber(WordCount.java:39) at source.WordCountTest.main(WordCountTest.java:35)